# R command multcompBoxplot with two plots side by side

Tags: r, boxplot

I ran into a little problem when using the `multcompBoxplot`function in the `multocompView` package. What I am trying to do is to put two box plots side by side from `multcompBoxplot` command. I use `par(mfrow=c(1,2)` and it did not work. Could anyone give me some advice how to deal with this? Here is an example from the `multocompView` website.

```
library(multcomp)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
data(cholesterol)
cholesterol$trt3 <- with(cholesterol, factor(
  as.character(trt), levels=levels(trt)[c(5:4,1:3)]))
multcompBoxplot(response ~ trt3, cholesterol,
                sortFn=NULL)
multcompBoxplot(response ~ trt3, cholesterol,
                sortFn=NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?
Then use `boxplot` instead of `multcomBoxplot`

```
library(multcomp)
data(cholesterol)
cholesterol$trt3 <- with(cholesterol, factor(
  as.character(trt), levels=levels(trt)[c(5:4,1:3)]))

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
boxplot(response ~ trt3, cholesterol,
                sortFn=NULL)
boxplot(response ~ trt3, cholesterol,
                sortFn=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: I try to put two box plots in a same figure. Like the one you show above, I want put another boxplot next (or under) the same figure. Like what the par(mfrow=c(1,2)) does.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know how to do with the normal box plot with the par(mfrow). I really want to know is if there is a way to apply this kind of technique with the multcompBoxplot function.